# Keep getting 404 error from API Post request to Perka.com Job Application using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

Perka has a cool tool where you apply to a job using their API. (*disclaimer: obviously if I can't figure it out, I doubt I qualify for job, but I just need to know what I'm doing wrong!*)

Here is my JavaScript Code using jQuery (I also wrote in C# and had same 404):

```
var appobject = {
    first_name: "John", last_name: "Doe", email: "blah@gmail.com",
    position_id: "JS", explanation: "blah blah blah",
    projects: ["http://www.google.com", "http://www.yahoo.com/", "http://www.facebook.com", "http://www.amazon.com"],
    source: "some guy told me about it",
    resume: "ahugelongstringofcharacters"
};    

$.ajax({
    url: "https://api.perka.com/1/communication/job/apply",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    processData:false,
    data: JSON.stringify(appobject)
})
```

No matter what I do, I get a 404 error.

Here are the API requirements:

[image of API Requirements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rxjzq.png)

The console always shows this after the request:

```
{"data":{},"errors":{"Not Found":"Endpoint not found"}}
```

I can see the payload and it appears to be correctly formatted:

[screenshot of Header & Payload Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fynhf.png)

There is an OPTIONS request being sent first, but that doesn't affect the POST request, right? (I've been reading on CORS, but I still can't answer that question myself yet.)

I've also tried:

- Various alterations to endpoint. (Since this is a job application, maybe they're testing me. If so, they have 100 copies of my resume now.)
- Using RestSharp in C# console app.
- Using online tools to validate I encoded my pdf file correctly.
- Yelling at computer.

Also, if the data is incorrectly formatted (my suspicion), would a 404 error be returned?

Lastly, if any of you have suggestions for excellent API books/training for both using and creating RESTful Services, please let me know. I obviously have a long way to go.

Comment: 404 usually means the endpoint/resource is not found. Despite the response being a generic 404, the actual content is customized. Looks like it really is not found. {
  "data": {},
  "errors": {
    "Not Found": "Endpoint not found"
  }
}

Comment: I am having the same error, did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Henry, no, I never did find a solution. I have tried everything I can think of. Perhaps it's some sort of test where you have to figure out some obscure solution, but I'm a beginner, so it's beyond me.

Comment: To be honest, this should be simple. Im not totally convinced its us and not that the actual server is failing to accept the request.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be using an outdated image and therefore an outdated URL. Your image has:

`Endpoint: https://api.perka.com/1/communication/job/apply`

But [this page](https://medium.com/perka-pencraft/apply-by-api-attracts-the-best-engineers-to-perka-heres-why-51a4b7d04720#.x2un4bbak) shows a different url:

`Endpoint: https://getperka.com/api/2/apply`

[image]

Comment: Yes, in my research I found this url also. This endpoint gives a different error. I think it was a 'not-authorized' error or something else.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a direct fix for you, but I can provide you with some information that might lead you to the path you seek.

First, the endpoint not found error can be a lot of things:

- The API URL you have is missing something that holds the command you are trying to execute. For instance, some APIs have a base URL, but then additional pathing that indicates if you are trying to push, get, etc.
- The API URL is invalid (perhaps deprecated)
- The API URL you have is not a URL that can be accessed without prior authentication. Meaning, this API may not be accessible from any request point. Many APIs now require OAuth handshakes prior to API calls that will acknowledge and authorize a request to it. It could also be that if the API is some type of subscription service that it can only be accessed from certain domains (see HTTP-REFERRER).
- The JSON you are passing is invalid or missing crucial parameters needed to tell the API what to do. This is relevant to the below:

While the code updates below probably won't solve your issue, they could be helpful in getting you closer to the solution. Consider revising your code to the following:

```
var appobject = {
    first_name: "John", last_name: "Doe", email: "blah@gmail.com",
    position_id: "JS", explanation: "blah blah blah",
    projects: ["http://www.google.com", "http://www.yahoo.com/", "http://www.facebook.com", "http://www.amazon.com"],
    source: "some guy told me about it",
    resume: "ahugelongstringofcharacters"
};    

$.ajax({
    url: "https://api.perka.com/1/communication/job/apply",
    type: "POST",
//    contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    dataType: 'json',
    processData:false,
    data: appobject,
    error: function(__x, __h, __m) {
        console.log('API Call Errored', __m, __x, __h);
    }, success: function(__data) {
        console.log('API Returned Success', __data);
    }
});
```

I hope some of this information helps you.